# How requests using UrlFetchApp.fetch() get counted against rate-limit of AlphaVantage API?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, alpha-vantage

I am fetching technical indicator data from AlphaVantage API with the following code in Google Apps Script

```
function testing(){
   var day = new Date();
   if(day.getDay()==0||day.getDay()==6){return;}
   var hour = day.getHours();
   var minute = day.getMinutes();
   if((hour<6)||(hour>=13)){ //Don't call API outside of trading hours
    console.log('Normal  Month '+(day.getMonth()+1)+' Day '+day.getDate()+' Hour '+hour+' Minutes '+minute);
    return;
   }
   //Call API in trading hours
   console.log('API Month '+(day.getMonth()+1)+' Day '+day.getDate()+' Hour '+hour+' Minutes '+minute);
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var latest_cell = ss.getRangeByName('LATEST_RSI');
   var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=RSI&symbol=AAPL&interval=30min&time_period=78&series_type=open&apikey=KEY"; 
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   var json = JSON.parse(response);
   var res = parseFloat(Object.values(json['Technical Analysis: RSI'])[0]["RSI"])
   latest_cell.setValue(res);
}
```

I set a Google time-driven trigger to execute the code once every 30 minutes during trading hours. But I am getting the following error every now and then.

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

This error happens on the line where I call `parseFloat()`, and occurs due to the API limit being reached so nothing is fetched from the URL. My current API key limit is 5 reqs/min and 500 reqs/day. I initially thought the issue was the way AlphaVantage counts API requests. However, I tried entering the URL in a browser, the limit behaves as expected as being counted each time I go to the link. So I am not understanding how I am violating the limit if I'm calling the code with Google triggers once every 30 minutes.

Normal JSON response looks like the following

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1: Symbol": "AAPL",
    "2: Indicator": "Relative Strength Index (RSI)",
    "3: Last Refreshed": "2020-06-15 16:00:00",
    "4: Interval": "30min",
    "5: Time Period": 78,
    "6: Series Type": "open",
    "7: Time Zone": "US/Eastern Time"
  },
  "Technical Analysis: RSI": {
    "2020-06-15 16:00": {
      "RSI": "54.5592"
    },
    "2020-06-15 15:30": {
      "RSI": "55.3796"
    }
    ...
}
```

Reaching limit error, the response is

```
{ Note: 'Thank you for using Alpha Vantage! Our standard API call frequency is 5 calls per minute and 500 calls per day. Please visit https://www.alphavantage.co/premium/ if you would like to target a higher API call frequency.' }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to do it this way:`var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   var robj = JSON.parse(response);
   var res = parseFloat(robj['Technical Analysis: RSI'][0]["RSI"])
   latest_cell.setValue(res);`

Comment: Because the json response is an object of objects but not in array form, I don't think it works that way.

Comment: Object.values() does really make that much sense there to me.  Can we see a liitle more of the JSON

Comment: Actually if you want to get more help with the JSON put a javascript tag on this.

Comment: That might be a problem with GAS time-based triggers firing randomly sometimes :( Do you get a `200` response code when you exceed rate limit? You might want to add either: 1. A guard for "last execution datetime", 2. A guard  `getResponseCode() >= 400`. 3. Add guard for `if(!json) { //cleanup and exit }` Checked the API docs - hate it when documentation does not include a list of API response codes (maybr I am just blind, but I don't see them doc'ed).

Comment: @user2805620 - could you please add what `response.getResponseCode()` returns? And it would be great if you could confirm how many runs of your function are logged in Stackdriver - this might be the root cause

Comment: @OlegValter `response.getResponseCode()` returns 200. There are 350 total executions of the function since june 10 with error rate of 6.86%

Comment: Thank you - you did a bit too much :) I just meant: how many executions of the trigger do you see during 30 minute window for the last day? Does anything strike you as odd - like triggers firing more frequently than they should? P.s. Please, add the status code to your question

Comment: Oh, and one more thing to check (this may sound too obvious, but it won't hurt to check) - what does the [triggers tab](https://script.google.com/home/triggers) say about the number of installed triggers for this project?

Comment: @OlegValter As far as I can see, the executions tab indicates it as being fired every 30 minutes. The failed executions seem non-deterministic, but they don't seem to happen because of the trigger firing more than usual. There is only one trigger installed for the project.

Comment: @user2805620 - could you please clarify what you mean by "seem non-deterministic, but they don't seem..." - do they sporadically fail in between 30-minute intervals? Please, take a screenshot of the executions tab for a few of those and updare the question - am curious to see details. As for one trigger - that's good, one less thing that could go wrong, thanks!